# RNPickerSelect remove "Select an item..."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using RNPickerSelect to as a dropdown in react-native app.

```
<RNPickerSelect
            onValueChange={(value) => setCountry(value)}
            value={country}
            items={[
                { label: 'United States', value: 'us' },
                { label: 'Canada', value: 'ca' },
            ]}
        />
```

and I need two countries, default always should be us, but when I click on it, it shows "Select an item..." which could be also selected. What is the way to remove that option?

Answer (score 2):

pass blank object in placeholder props

```
    <RNPickerSelect
        placeholder={{}}
        onValueChange={(value) => setCountry(value)}
        value={country}
        items={[
            { label: 'United States', value: 'us' },
            { label: 'Canada', value: 'ca' },
        ]}
    />
```